# War file deploys successfully on Apache tomcat 8.5.4 mac OSX but localhost:8080 says page not found

Tags: apache, tomcat, intellij-idea

[image]I am developing a web app using intellij idea & tomcat server. The application was working fine but after I restarted the server. it deployed the application to server but localhost:8080 throws 404 satus.

Comment: what's under your application?

Comment: I have solved it anyway thanks @jerry chin